# Compile Failures After Fontspec Update

Tags: miktex, fontspec, unicode-math

I updated packages (Windows 10 / MikTex 2.9), which included a January 26, 2020 update to fontspec.  On my first compile (LuaTex) after the update, a file that compiled fine immediately before the update reported several errors.  I will provide sample code that now fails and then discuss the errors further below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math} 
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
%
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The errors shown on the terminal:

```
Undefined control sequence \setmathfont   
Undefined control sequence \setsansfont
Undefined control sequence \begin
```

A couple of snippets from the log file:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {\str_lowercase:f 
                  {\l__fontspec_extension_tl }}
l.8 \setmathfont
              {TeX Gyre Termes Math}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {\str_lowercase:f 
                  {\l__fontspec_extension_tl }}
l.11 \begin
         {document}
```

It strikes me as unlikely that this could be caused by fontspec because there would be multiple reports by now.  But I can't think of other alternatives, unless the update somehow corrupted my MikTex environment.

Suggestions?

Comment: your expl3 has not been updated

Comment: note that the terminal will not say `Undefined control sequence \setmathfont   ` the error message is as you show, showing it is  `\str_lowercase:f` that is undefined, not `\setmathfont`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you.  The January 31, 2020 update to expl3 is not available yet on MikTex (I think it is delivered through l3kernel), but if you convert to an answer I will upvote once I can do the update.

Comment: it doesn't need to be _that_ new, more likely you have an older one in your path somewhere I would guess, or the usual miktex issue that you need to update both user and admin modes. (I know nothing about miktex)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem as you described above. After small observation of my updated Miktex installation, `l3kernel` package missed in system. Please try to install it manually over Miktex Console.

Comment: I am the OP.  Thanks to David Carlisle, I understood there was some kind of problem with l3kernel.  My solution was to run the MikTex Package Manager.  First I ran "mpm --verify" to see if there was a problem with any of my installed packages.  It indicated that l3kernel (plus three others) needed to be reinstalled.  So, for those packages, I ran "mpm --uninstall=<package name>" and then "mpm --install=<package name>".  After that, everything worked.  I did not have an admin mode, so the usual advice of updating both did not apply to me.